# Inheritance and data binding on Grails

Tags: grails, inheritance, data-binding

I have a problem to use data binding with inherit models. That's my code:

```
class Member {
   int age

   static belongsTo = [Family]
   static constraints = {}
}

class Parent extends Member {
   String name
   static constraints = {}
}

class Family {
    String name
    List members
    static hasMany = [members: Member]
    static constraints = {}
}


def test(){
    def bindingMap = [name: 'toto', members:[[age: 18, name: '1'],[age: 18]]]
    def family = new Family()
    family.properties = bindingMap
    family.save(flush: true)
    def get = Family.get(family.id)
    // here family only contains Member and no Parent, as expected...
}
```

With this code, as you can see, I'm not able to create Parent with data binding.
Anyone have an idea?

Thanks